# three.js failing to use pre-created canvas

Tags: three.js

I want to use a pre-created canvas with three.js. From the tutorials and other posts I've read, this should work:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    // <--- This causes the error below!
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas } );
```

However, in my browser console (Safari v14 and Chrome v86), I get the following error:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.
```

I've also tried adding

```
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

and using:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    // <--- This causes the same error!
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
   canvas: canvas,
});
```

and get the same issues.

I've also tried adding:

```
window.onload = function() {
  ...
};
```

to ensure the DOM has loaded, etc.

If I remove the `getContext("2d")` lines then it works?

I'm using three.js version 0.120.

Why does this cause an issue?

Comment: Works okay for me (r122, Chrome 86). I went to https://threejs.org/docs then opened a console. I entered: `let c = document.createElement('canvas'); let r = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: c});` And everything went off without a hitch.

Comment: Update my question above... This is strange. Yes the code works. If I add `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` between defining the canvas and the renderer then it fails. Didn't think it was relevant hence not including above...

Comment: Ignore my current answer... I'm updating it based on this new info.

Comment: New answer posted. Based on your comments, it sounds like you'll need to find a different way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three.js only throws this error in one place, and luckily it's doing something very simple: Getting a context from a `canvas`. It uses `HTMLCanvasElement.getContext` to do this, and only throws the error if the result is `null`.

[`HTMLCanvasElement.getContext`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) will only allow you to request one context type. You can request the same type (or compatible, in the case of `webgl` and `webgl2`) again, but it will return the original context created on the canvas. After the first request establishes the in-use context, subsequent requests for incompatible types will return `null`.

```js
let ctx_2d_1 = mycanvas.getContext( '2d' )
let ctx_2d_2 = mycanvas.getContext( '2d' )
console.log( ctx_2d_1 === ctx_2d_2 ) // true
```

```js
let ctx_2d = mycanvas.getContext( '2d' )
let ctx_webgl = mycanvas.getContext( 'webgl' )

console.log( ctx_2d ) // CanvasRenderingContext2D
console.log( ctx_webgl  ) // null
```

```js
let ctx_webgl = mycanvas.getContext( 'webgl' )
let ctx_2d = mycanvas.getContext( '2d' )

console.log( ctx_webgl  ) // WebGLRenderingContext
console.log( ctx_2d ) // null
```

Because you are creating the `2d` context before calling the `WebGLRenderer` constructor, the constructor can't get a valid `WebGLRenderingContext` from the canvas. Instead, it gets a `null`, and so it throws the error.

If you want to draw 2D on top of 3D (or vice versa), you will either need to layer canvases of different contexts, or use a plane to render the 2D information as a texture within the WebGL (three.js) context.

Comment: Thanks, that works but introduces a new problem as a WebGL context doesn't allow me to use drawImage().  Let me revisit what I'm trying to do to see if I can find a different approach.

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01. I'm trying to find how to layer canvases. Can you point me at a good source?

Comment: @mstreffo That will be done with CSS positioning and z-indexing. Whatever your favorite HTML/CSS tutorial site is should be good enough. :)